# Can I exclude files from every pre-commit hook except for one without repeating myself?

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

I would like to make a Git repo that’s [REUSE](https://reuse.software/) compliant. I want to use [the reuse pre-commit hook](https://github.com/fsfe/reuse-tool#run-as-pre-commit-hook) to help ensure that I’m compliant. [The REUSE Specification](https://reuse.software/spec/) requires that I make a folder called “LICENSES” that contains each of the licenses that my project uses. I’m using several other hooks, and I don’t want those hooks to check or modify anything in the `LICENSES/` folder. I want every hook other than reuse to exclude `LICENSES/`. (Side note: at the moment, it looks like the reuse hook isn’t affected by excluding `LICENSES/`, but that should probably be fixed). Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

```
exclude: '^LICENSES/'
repos:
    -
        repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
        rev: v4.0.1
        hooks:
            - id: check-case-conflict
            - id: end-of-file-fixer
            - id: mixed-line-ending
            - id: trailing-whitespace
    # I’m using identity instead of reuse here for testing and to better
    # illustrate the problem.
    -
        repo: meta
        hooks:
            -
                id: identity
                exclude: "^$"
```

That didn’t work. It looks like the per-hook exclude pattern applies in addition to the global one. I wanted the per-hook exclude pattern to apply instead of the global one.

I could use a per-hook exclude pattern on every hook except one:

```
repos:
    -
        repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
        rev: v4.0.1
        hooks:
            -
                id: check-case-conflict
                exclude: &exclude_pattern '^LICENSES/'
            -
                id: end-of-file-fixer
                exclude: *exclude_pattern
            -
                id: mixed-line-ending
                exclude: *exclude_pattern
            -
                id: trailing-whitespace
                exclude: *exclude_pattern
    # I’m using identity instead of reuse here for testing and to better
    # illustrate the problem.
    -
        repo: meta
        hooks:
            - id: identity
```

But, then I would be repeating myself. I think that I might be able to repeat myself less using merge keys, but [I don’t think that those are supported](https://ktomk.github.io/writing/yaml-anchor-alias-and-merge-key.html). Is there anyway to avoid repeating myself or to repeat myself less?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there is not without specifying an `exclude` on each hook as you've found

the top level `exclude` is a shortcut which is [applied to all hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-exclude)

I would recommend just adding `exclude` to the hooks which *would* modify the `LICENSES`

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Is there any documentation about how to specify files or folders to be excluded from pre-commit scripts other than "(optional: default ^$) global file exclude pattern. new in 1.1.0.". I not familiar with what ^$ means and what way of parsing pre-commit uses for this. How dies the _exclude pattern_work?

Comment: https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions